# ¿Cómo eliminar un array hijo dentro de un array padre en PHP?

Tags: php, array, session, delete

Hola alguien podría ayudarme estoy realizando un carrito de compras y quiero eliminar un array hijo dentro de otro array padre, para poder agregar un nuevo array hijo, dependiendo del valor de mi variable `$_POST['product_id']` que se elimine el array con ese valor, mi código:

```
<?php
/*
* Agrega el producto a la variable de sesión de productos.
*/
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST)){
    if(isset($_POST["product_id"]) && isset($_POST["q"])){
        // si es el primer producto simplemente lo agregamos
        if(empty($_SESSION["cart"])){
            $_SESSION["cart"]=array( array("product_id"=>$_POST["product_id"],"q"=> $_POST["q"]));
            var_export($_SESSION["cart"]);
        }else{
            // apartir del segundo producto:
            $cart = $_SESSION["cart"];
            $repeated = False;
            // recorremos el carrito en busqueda de producto repetido
            foreach ($cart as $c) {
                // si el producto esta repetido rompemos el ciclo
                if($c["product_id"]==$_POST["product_id"] && $c["q"]==$_POST["q"]){
                    $repeated=true;
                    break;
                }else if($c["product_id"]==$_POST["product_id"] && $c["q"]!=$_POST["q"]){
                    //despues de comparar que la cantidad '$_POST["q"]' sea diferente de la ya existente eliminamos
                    unset($_SESSION["cart"]);
                    var_export($_SESSION["cart"]);
                    $repeated=true;
                }
            }
            // si el producto es repetido no hacemos nada, simplemente redirigimos
            if($repeated){
                print "<script>alert('Error: Producto Repetido!');</script>";
            }else{
                // si el producto no esta repetido entonces lo agregamos a la variable cart y despues asignamos la variable cart a la variable de sesion
                array_push($cart, array("product_id"=>$_POST["product_id"],"q"=> $_POST["q"]));
                $_SESSION["cart"] = $cart;
                var_export($_SESSION["cart"]);
            }
        }
        if($_POST["productA"]=="extracto"){
            //print "<script>window.location='../producto.php#extracto';</script>";
        }
        if($_POST["productA"]=="vaina"){
            print "<script>window.location='../producto.php#vaina';</script>";
        }
        if($_POST["productA"]=="cafe"){
            print "<script>window.location='../producto.php#cafe';</script>";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Pero cuando ejecuto me elimina por completo todo el array y no solo el que necesito eliminar para reemplazarlo por un nuevo array.

Alguien me podría indicar que estoy realizando mal para eliminar el array y no todos los demás es mi primera vez realizando un arreglo dentro de otro y guardándolo en variables de sesión

Les agradeceré mucho su apoyo

Comment: Buenas, tienes demasiado codigo para lo que intentas, al margen de la respuesta te aconsejo que refactorices un poco porque ese codigo va a ser inmantenible si sigues alimentando a la bestia. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que tienes un error lógico en tu código. Si haces `unset($array)`, eliminas todo el arreglo y su contenido. Para especificar un elemento en específico recuerda hacer referencia a él, mediante su $key. Ejemplo:

```
unset($array[$key])
```

Si quieres acceder a un array hijo:

```
$codigo_id = 12;
unset($array[$key][$codigo_id])
```

Suerte!

Answer (score -1):

Para ello usa la siguiente estructura:

```
$product_id=1;
$q=100;

$product_id2=2;
$q2=12;

$_SESSION["cart"][$product_id]=array("q"=> $q);
$_SESSION["cart"][$product_id2]=array("q"=>$q2);

//Eliminar producto del carrito con la id de $product_id;
unset($_SESSION["cart"][$product_id]);
```

[Ejemplo carrito](https://syframework.alwaysdata.net/9z8)

Comment: No lleves al usuario a otro sitio para responder una pregunta donde deberias colocar el codigo.